# Drawn images do not stay on screen

Tags: java, swing, drawing

I am drawing onto a JPanel using getGraphics and the drawLine and fillOval commands but it is very temperamental when running the program.  However, when I debug it it draws every time.

```
draw.drawPoints(drawing.getGraphics(), xCoord, yCoord);
```

Calls:

```
public void drawPoints (Graphics g, int x, int y){
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.fillOval(x, y, 5, 5);
}
```

edit: It wont always draw.  Most of the time is stays blank.

Comment: What do you mean by 'temperamental'? Exactly what is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **I am drawing onto a JPanel using getGraphics**

You should not draw stuff on the `JPanel` by getting a `Graphics` object from `drawing.getGraphics()`.

Instead, you should override the `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method and do your painting there.

A simple example to get you started:

```
container.add(new JPanel() {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        drawPoints(g, xCoord, yCoord);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do that every time the object is repainted.